# Typoscript: Display register value as text

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I'm using the extension seo_dynamic_tag, which is a fantastic plugin for TYPO3 SEO purposes.
It uses registers to store the generated meta description and keywords. Later on in the script, the page metadata is filled in from these registers:

```
page {
    meta {
        description {
            field  >
            data = register:description
        }
        keywords {
            field >
            data = register:keywordss
        }
    }
1000 < temp.seo
}
```

So far it works like charm.
But in addition I'd like to display a TEXT object on the page with the meta description on the bottom. The text should read the meta description and some other stuff. That's where I need your help.
I tried to do the "magic" like this:

```
temp.description = COA
temp.description {
    10 = TEXT
    10.value = Meta description: {register:description}
    stdWrap.insertData = 1
}
lib.footer < temp.description
```

This simply does not work. If I want to display something else, for example {page:title} or {date:y-m-d}, data insertion works. For register:xxx it doesn't.
I already spent lots of hours to google out my desired solution, but no success :(

Do you have any idea what I'm missing here?
I'm using TYPO3 4.5.3 (I know I should update ;)).

Many thanks in advance for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `stdWrap.insertData = 1` is applied to your COA-object, and not to your TEXT-object. You can instead set `10.insertData = 1` or just write the following:

```
10 = TEXT
10.data = register:description
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but for me it did not display anything. For other data (for example date:y-m-d) it works and outputs the text, but not for registers. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Maybe the register is not filled correctly? Try ``debug:data`` to see what you can use.

Comment: That's a good point. You must check where exactly your register is filled. Maybe it is not available at the point where you want to load it. http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/LoadRegister/Index.html